# Properly defining font-family in @font-face CSS rules

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts, font-family, google-webfonts

I recently came across the `@font-family` CSS rule as I was looking to use web fonts on my website.

Coming to the point, I've seen two variants in @font-family CSS code, which you can see below:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Droid Serif'; /* NOTE THIS LINE */
  font-weight: normal; /* NOTE THIS LINE */
  font-style: normal; /* NOTE THIS LINE */
  src: url('DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.eot');
  src: url('DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   local('Droid Serif'), local('DroidSerifRegular'),
   url('DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
   url('DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
   url('DroidSerif-Regular-webfont.svg#DroidSerifRegular') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Droid Serif'; /* NOTE THIS LINE */
  font-weight: normal; /* NOTE THIS LINE */
  font-style: italic; /* NOTE THIS LINE */
  src: url('DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.eot');
  src: url('DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   local('Droid Serif'), local('DroidSerifItalic'),
   url('DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
   url('DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
   url('DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.svg#DroidSerifItalic') format('svg');
}
```

and this is another:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DroidSerifRegular'; /* NOTE THIS LINE */
  font-weight: normal; /* NOTE THIS LINE */
  font-style: normal; /* NOTE THIS LINE */
  src: url('DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.eot');
  src: url('DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   local('Droid Serif'), local('DroidSerifItalic'),
   url('DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
   url('DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
   url('DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.svg#DroidSerifItalic') format('svg');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'DroidSerifItalic'; /* NOTE THIS LINE */
  font-weight: normal; /* NOTE THIS LINE */
  font-style: normal; /* NOTE THIS LINE */
  src: url('DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.eot');
  src: url('DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
   local('Droid Serif'), local('DroidSerifItalic'),
   url('DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
   url('DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
   url('DroidSerif-Italic-webfont.svg#DroidSerifItalic') format('svg');
}
```

Compare the lines that I've commented with `/* NOTE THIS LINE */`

The first variant is by [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts), while the second one is by [Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/). So, is one of these two wrong? (Just wanted to confirm, although both are very reliable sources.)

If acceptable, which one of the two would I be better off with?

Comment: I was taught that you should never ever specify a font style in the `font-family` property. But then, it could be my knowledge is outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the first example, though hard to believe, is correct; notice how the Droid Serif Regular is being declared as font weight normal and font style normal...how you'd expect a regular font to be displayed. the second declaration, it's calling in Droid Serif Italic, and setting it to to font-style:italic; this allows you to use multiple fonts within a family. If you wanted to add a bold font, you'd apply the same @font-face rule except you'd change font-weight:bold, while leaving font-style:normal and declaring the same font family.

fontsquirrel really does a great job with rendering @font-face rules, actually i've read about this technique there. surprised it's not being implemented. you can read more about this here: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/font-face_tip_define_font-weight_and_font-style_to_keep_your_css_simple/