# Defining small-caps font-variant with @font-face

Tags: css, font-face

How do I add a small-caps font as a variant?

I’m using Jos Buivenga’s Fontin, which has its small-caps variant as a seperate font rather than as an OpenType-style feature. This CSS snippet properly defines the regular, bold, and italic fonts in the family, but not the small-caps one. How can I make this work?

```
/* A font by Jos Buivenga (exljbris) -> www.exljbris.com */
@font-face {
    font-family: "Fontin";
    src: url(../Fonts/Fontin-Regular.ttf) format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Fontin";
    font-style: italic;
    src: url(../Fonts/Fontin-Italic.ttf) format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Fontin";
    font-weight: bold;
    src: url(../Fonts/Fontin-Bold.ttf) format("truetype");
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Fontin";
    font-variant: small-caps;
    src: url(../Fonts/Fontin-SmallCaps.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

Related: *[How to add multiple font files for the same font?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2436749/95580)* and *[Properly defining font-family in @font-face CSS rules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10364458/95580)*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that the effective way is to fake the small-caps typeface as a font family, declaring it with e.g.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Fontin Small Caps";
    src: url(Fontin-SmallCaps.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

(note the lack of `font-style` setting, defaulting it to `normal`) and using a rule like

```
p { font-family: Fontin Small Caps; }
```

without setting `font-style`.

Testing with the logical way, as described in the question, and using the .ttf font from http://www.exljbris.com/fontin.html I noticed that Firefox, Chrome, Opera all apply “fake small-caps” (i.e., uppercase letters in reduced size), when I set `font-family: Fontin; font-variant: small-caps;`. This is sad, but not very surprising.

The odd thing is that Firefox and Opera, but not Chrome, use the small-caps typeface of Fontin when I only set `font-family: Fontin`. This does not happen if I remove the `@font-face` rule that has `font-style: small-caps`. So the browsers are really hostile to the logical way using small capitals.

Comment: Re-reading the official documentation for `@font-face`, seems you're right: `font-variant` is not supported.

Comment: @J.C.Salomon. right, by the CSS3 Fonts draft, `font-variant: small-caps` in `@font-face` should affect the rendering of the chosen font (typeface), in practice via OpenType features, not the choice of font.