# Small-caps not rendering in chrome using web font

Tags: css, google-chrome, webfonts, woff

I'm having problems getting my web font in small caps using "font-variant: small-caps". Here's my findings and what I went through, ruling out possible problems :

1. My initial thought was that the .woff file was not rendering small-caps for some reason. I've ruled this out because the font renders fine in Safari and Firefox, which as far as I know use the .woff format.
2. My second thought was that it was a webkit issue, but as Safari displays it fine, I don't think it is.
3. I'm not using twitter bootstrap, so no `text-rendering: optimizelegibility`, I've also tried resetting it to auto.
4. I tried the `font-feature-settings: 'smcp'` including browser prefixes, which doesn't render small caps (only the first letter is capitalized, across all browsers)

Am I missing something out?

**edit**

After further research, I found a fix, which is to add `font-variant:small-caps` to the `@font-face`, like so :

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'MYFONT';
    src:url('../fonts/MYFONT.eot');
    src:url('../fonts/MYFONT.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/MYFONT.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/MYFONT.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/MYFONT.svg#myfont') format('svg');
    font-variant:small-caps
}
```

It turns out that only the stack was affected by this. Assigning a `@font-face` like so works as expected, in every font format supported by Chrome:

```
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family:'MYFONTttf';
    src:url('../fonts/MYFONT.ttf') format('truetype');
}
</style>

<div style="font-family:MYFONTttf; font-variant:small-caps">
    works as expected, in small-caps
</div>
```

Comment: Are you really gonna not tell us the font you're using?  And the rest of your code and where you get the font, etc

Comment: Test your assumption if Firefox and Safari really use the .woff file. Also, Safari uses Webkit, but Chrome uses Blink, which by now may already be significantly different from Webkit.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key is, oddly enough, not to include the SVG-formatted font. Including just the WOFF and TTF seems to make it display alright.

I generated my various font files using Font Squirrel, so I ended up with `.woff`, `.ttf`, `.svg`, and `.eot` files. My font-related CSS was:

`@font-face {
  font-family: "foo";
  src: url(/fonts/foo.eot);
  src: url(/fonts/foo?#iefix) format('eot'), url(/fonts/foo.woff) format('woff'), url(/fonts/foo.ttf) format('truetype'), url(/fonts/foo.svg) format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}`

generated by Compass from:

`+font-face("foo", font-files("/fonts/foo.woff", "/fonts/foo.ttf", "/fonts/foo.svg"), "/fonts/foo.eot", normal, normal)`

which is in keeping with [Compass's SASS font-face guidelines](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/font_face/).

Removing the reference to the SVG seemed to fix it. I also tried switching the order of the TTF and the SVG (breaking Compass's 'recommended order' for font files) but that didn't help.

Taking a quick look around, it seems like Chrome has other miscellaneous problems with rendering SVG fonts. This isn't a really elegant solution but it might be necessary until Chrome sorts out its SVG issues.

Comment: Removing SVG indeed fixes it, but adding font-variant to the font-stack does as well. Are you exclusively talking about small-caps?

Comment: Yeah, I've only run into this with small-caps. Do you mean you solved it like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14527408/defining-small-caps-font-variant-with-font-face)? This seems like a cleaner solution than removing the SVG, but the typeface I was using didn't come with a small-caps font and I wasn't sure how to generate my own. How did you do it?